# Temporal calculations

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, astronomy

I'm currently developing a javascript application in which I want to calculate the approximate position of the sun. This works quite fine but requires the value for deltaT to be set depending on the year for which I want to calculate the solar position (deltaT corresponds to the difference between universal time and terrestrial time).

Currently, I'm using a default value for my calculation. However, I need a different value for each year to improve the precision of my algorithm.

Is there any API or library from which I can obtain such values? Basically, I need to get the current terrestrial time and the universal time. Unfortunately, the javascript built-in Date object does not provide the desired functionality. Likewise, moment.js seems to lack the desired functionality, either.

Comment: Are you looking for a database of astronomical data?

Answer (score 0):

On this website they may be achieving what you want:
https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/deltat/deltat.htm

And you can find in the javascript file of the website the javascript function they use to evaluate Delta-T, it's called deltatime().